# Webshop for digital goods with voucher / gift card system

Tags: download, shopping

I'm searching for a webshop which provides the following:

- The shop offers digital goods (like mp3)
- User can buy a voucher / gift card @Reseller (Or there is a code provided in the CD)
- User can enter his code @ webshop and gets the download (unregistered)
- User can enter his code @ webshop and download is added to his/her library (registered)

optional:
Resellers can buy codes from the Webshop

I already tried prestashop as it looks quite nice. But it needs a lot of custom programming (and has a very strange voucher-system). Customer has to add the File into the basket and add the voucher at checkout. I want to skip that ;)

Is there a Webshop (Or CMS + Plugin) which provides the things I need? (it could also be a CMS with a Storage/Folder Plugin (like joomla + K2) and a possibility to activate downloads via unique Codes.)

Any ideas are highly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Pro Webmasters as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. You should consider asking this type of question in [chat].

Comment: I want opinionated answers (And, as I didn't find any system which provides this thing, i hoped someone could answer the question like:
"Take this shop, this and this addon with this special setting and you have what you want"
But I will ask this in the webmasters chat!